# Best approach for API Versioning

Tags: api, nginx, sails.js

What is the best way to version API?

For example I am using sails js for API backend, to version the API:
Should it be done in my application, (in the controller) (at app level)?
Should I use the routes.js for versioning the API (framework level)?
Should I do it with nginx (server level)?
Should it be done at API Gateway (API Management)?

Answer (score 0):

My approach for api versioning is at application level:

Create subfolder for your controllers as:

```
/controllers/v1/UserController.js
/controllers/v2/UserController.js
```

In your routes.js file, add as follow:

```
'POST /api/v2/user': 'v2/UserController.create',
'POST /api/v1/user': 'v2/UserController.create',
```

And in your policies.js, you can add middlewares like this:

```
'v2/UserController': {
    'create': ['isAuthenticated','isAuthorized']
   }
```

My current sails' version is: 0.12.3.
At this time, model versioning is not supported by using subfolders.